# Cancel all expo local scheduled notifications on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, notifications, uilocalnotification, expo

I tried scheduling local notifications using expo (react native) and something very strange is happening.

This is the code I wrote:

```
const localNotification = {
  title: 'test',
  body: 'test body',
  ios: {
    sound: true
  }
};

let t = new Date();
t.setSeconds(t.getSeconds() + 10);

const schedulingOptions = {
  time: t, // (date or number) — A Date object representing when to fire the notification or a number in Unix epoch time. Example: (new Date()).getTime() + 1000 is one second from now.
  repeat: 'minute'
};

Notifications.scheduleLocalNotificationAsync(localNotification, schedulingOptions);
```

Then I started to receive the same notification every time the app is in background.

I removed that piece of code to use `Notifications.presentLocalNotificationAsync()` instead and I expected the previous notification to stop appearing as `Notifications.scheduleLocalNotificationAsync()` is never called anywhere in the whole app.

On Android I rebooted the phone and the notification doesn't appear anymore, but on iOS even after rebooting and reinstalling expo I keep getting the same scheduled notification.

I tried calling `Notifications.cancelAllScheduledNotificationsAsync()` with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

When your code called `scheduleLocalNotificationAsync()` it registered a recurring notification with the OS - removing the code isn't enough.

I think `Notifications.cancelAllScheduledNotificationsAsync()` is what you're looking for:

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#notificationscancelallschedulednotificationsasync

Answer (score 0):

import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';
import {
cancelAllScheduledNotificationsAsync
} from 'expo-notifications';

```
const cancelAllNotifications = async () => {
try {
    await Notifications.cancelAllScheduledNotificationsAsync();
    console.log('All pending notifications have been canceled.');
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error canceling notifications:', error);
    }
};
```